# MASM - HeapAlloc throws exception

Tags: memory, assembly, masm, heapalloc

I'm here again. I'm using masm .dll in c# application, but now my code throws 'System.AccessViolationException' in line: `INVOKE HeapAlloc, edx, 0,  <size>`
Can you tell me what cause problem?

Here is my ASM code:

```
invoke GetProcessHeap
mov edx, eax
INVOKE HeapAlloc, edx, 0,  dlText
mov tab, eax
INVOKE HeapAlloc, edx, 0,  dlText
mov wynik, eax
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of error. I was using **edx** instead of **ebx** ;)